# Lock file error when importing resource in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to import 2 existing azure resources (1 vnet and 1 resource group).

If I add the following to my main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "my-vnet" {
}
```

and run `terraform import azurerm_virtual_network.my-vnet /subscriptions/11111111/resourceGroups/my-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/my-vnet-01`

Everything works perfectly, the `terraform.tfstate` file gets updated with the vnet information etc.

If I then add the following to the main.tf

```
resource "azurem_resource_group" "my-net-rsg" {
}
```

and run `terraform import azurem_resource_group.my-net-rsg /subscriptions/11111111/resourceGroups/my-net-rsg`

I get the following error
[image]

If I then remove

```
resource "azurem_resource_group" "my-net-rsg" {
}
```

and run the same `terraform import azurem_resource_group.my-net-rsg /subscriptions/11111111/resourceGroups/my-net-rsg` I get an error (quite rightly & expectedly) saying

```
Before importing this resource, please create its configuration in the root module. For example:  

resource "azurem_resource_group" "my-net-rsg" {
# (resource arguments)
}
```

Even if I literally copy and paste that output back into my `main.tf` file I get the same error from the screen shot above.

I've tried only having the resource group config
I've tried having the resource config first before the vnet
I've tried a fresh `terraform init` in a different directory and walking through the process again.

Every time if I have the resource group in the `main.tf` it complains about the lock file.

Comment: Typo? `azurem` vs `azurerm`?

Comment: @MarkoE Well I fell like an idiot. So powershell just mimics back whatever you call the resource in the error. Which actually makes sense. So at some point I added the typo and then just kept repeating it. Even when I was copying it back from powershell. Catch22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just going to delete the question as it is such a simple problem/solution, but because the error is so non-descript as to the cause this might be helpful to someone

Apparently[image]
Is terraform for you have a typo in your resource name.

`resource "azurem_resource_group"` should be (in this case) `resource "azurerm_resource_group"`

Comment: There is a simple explanation though: when you declare the `required_providers` block the shortened name is defined, e.g., for Azure it's usual to call it `azurerm` or `aws` for AWS provider, but you could call it anything you like. Then, in the next step you say `provider "azure" {}` using the short name. This helps Terraform differ between providers and know how to interpret the resource blocks. If Terrafrom sees a resource block for a provider that has not been declared in the `required_providers` or `providers` it suggests to initialize the configuration. :)